# Inconsistency in thermal expectation values of creation operators

Tags: field-theory, many-body

While studying many-body theory (in particular, field theory at positive temperatures) I came across the following exercise: given the grand-canonical Hamiltonian for a bosonic system
\begin{equation}
\hat{K}=\sum_a[(\epsilon_a-\mu)\hat{c}^\dagger_a\hat{c}_a+\gamma^*_a\hat{c}_a+\gamma_a\hat{c}^\dagger_a]
\end{equation}
where $\hat{c}_a$ and $\hat{c}^\dagger_a$ are the destruction and creation operators associated to a complete orthonormal system indexed by $a$, I have to calculate the expectation value
\begin{equation}
\langle \hat{c}_a\rangle_K=
\frac{1}{Z}\operatorname{tr}(e^{-\beta \hat{K}}\hat{c}_a).
\end{equation}

Denoting by $\hat{c}_a(\tau)_K=e^{\hat{K}\tau/\hbar}\hat{c}_ae^{-\hat{K}\tau/\hbar}$ the evolution in "imaginary time" of the operator, that is the solution of the Heisenberg equation
\begin{equation}
\hbar\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\tau}\hat{c}_a(\tau)_K=[\hat{K},\hat{c}_a(\tau)_K],
\end{equation}
which, if my computation is correct, equals
\begin{equation}
\hat{c}_a(\tau)_K=
e^{-(\epsilon_a-\mu)\tau/\hbar}\hat{c}_a-\gamma_a\frac{\tau}{\hbar}\hat{1},
\end{equation}
I can write
\begin{equation}
\langle\hat{c}_a\rangle_K=
\frac{1}{Z}\operatorname{tr}(e^{-\beta \hat{K}}\hat{c}_a)=
\frac{1}{Z}\operatorname{tr}(\hat{c}_ae^{-\beta \hat{K}})=
\frac{1}{Z}\operatorname{tr}(e^{-\beta \hat{K}}e^{\beta \hat{K}}\hat{c}_ae^{-\beta \hat{K}})=
\frac{1}{Z}\operatorname{tr}(e^{-\beta \hat{K}}\hat{c}_a(\hbar\beta)_K)
\end{equation}
and at the same time
\begin{equation}
\langle\hat{c}_a\rangle_K=
\frac{1}{Z}\operatorname{tr}(e^{-\beta \hat{K}}\hat{c}_a)=
\frac{1}{Z}\operatorname{tr}(e^{-\beta \hat{K}}\hat{c}_ae^{\beta \hat{K}}e^{-\beta \hat{K}})=
\frac{1}{Z}\operatorname{tr}(\hat{c}_a(-\hbar\beta)_Ke^{-\beta \hat{K}})=
\frac{1}{Z}\operatorname{tr}(e^{-\beta \hat{K}}\hat{c}_a(-\hbar\beta)_K).
\end{equation}
This is absurd, since
\begin{equation}
\hat{c}_a(\hbar\beta)_K-\hat{c}_a(-\hbar\beta)_K=
-2\sinh\bigl(\beta(\epsilon_a-\mu)\bigr)\hat{c}_a-2\beta\gamma_a\hat{1}
\end{equation}
therefore
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{tr}\bigl(e^{-\beta \hat{K}}[\hat{c}_a(\hbar\beta)_K-\hat{c}_a(-\hbar\beta)_K]\bigr)\ne 0
\end{equation}
while it *should* be zero, following from the equations above.
I must have made some mistake, but I can't see where... I need some external advice!